# Google Script / js script not updating current value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, rhino

This is the current code:
last question --> how do i make every single outcome in one string. (visit log in screenshot)

var outcome should be like :

Nik  |  HUR-L2  |  Laranite  |  4564 + "\n" + Tobi  |  CRU-L1  |  Quanti  |  513 + "\n"

[image]

Comment: It looks that the "Cloud-Logs" aren't complete and that you are using the old Google Apps Script editor.  Why are you using the old editor?  The second screenshot doesn't match the sample data (the sample data only have 5 rows but the value shown for `lastRow` is 40.

Comment: This question is not related to rhino, please remove the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just grab all table date at once via `getRange('your range').getValues()` and then filter it this way:

```js
const table = [  // just as an example
    [1235, 1],
    [4564, 0],
    [452, 1],
    [513, 1]
]

const values = table.filter(t => t[1] == 1).map(t => t[0])

console.log(values); // [ 1235, 452, 513 ]
```

For your case the code can be boiled down to this:

```
function test() {
  const sSheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Refinery");
  const table    = srcSheet.getRange("D:M").getValues(); // use "D2:M" if you have a header
  const values   = table.filter(t => t[9] == 1).map(t => t[0]);

  Logger.log(values); // [1235.0, 452.0, 513.0]
}
```

[image]

**Update**

If you want data from C, D, E you can do this:

```
const table    = srcSheet.getRange("C:M").getValues(); // get a wider range

const values_C = table.filter(t => t[10] == 1).map(t => t[0]);
const values_D = table.filter(t => t[10] == 1).map(t => t[1]);
const values_E = table.filter(t => t[10] == 1).map(t => t[2]);
```

The `table` is a table from a given range ("C:M"), where `table[0][0]` is `C`, `table[0][1]` is `D`, etc.

The `filter()` part removes from the table rows that don't have "1" in 10th column (`table[0][10]` is `M`).

The `map()` part removes all cells but one from every row.

Or (more efficient but less readable variant):

```
const [values_C, values_D, values_E] = 
      table.filter(t => t[9] == 1).map(t => [t[0], t[1], t[2]]);
```

This way you will get an `array`. To get a `string` you need one more step:

```
const values_C_string = value_C.join(", ") // [a,b,c] --> "a, b, c"
```

You can chain this step this way:

```
const values_C = table.filter(t => t[10] == 1).map(t => t[0]).join(", ");
```

Comment: lets say, i need the output of column C,D,E  in a string and also in their chronological order. how can i do this in the best way?

Comment: thanks alot, u're more worth than antimatter haha

Comment: Be aware, this example is not very efficient. It filters the table for three times. It makes sense to filter the table just once. Something like this: `var [values_C, values_D, values_E] = table.filter(t => t[3] == 1).map(t => [t[0], t[1], t[2]]);` You will get three arrays (or strings) with one step.

Comment: i made an update at the post above, i just dont understand why and even if i do var outcome += variable it's not appending it like in most other languages

Comment: It's a quite simply question. But it's too far from your original problem. It's almost impossible to make an answer as Update to the existing answers.You have to post it as a new question. I'm sure you will get answer pretty quick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233032/discussion-between-yuri-khristich-and-thefirefox).

Answer (score 1):

```
function Test() {
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var val = srcSheet.getRange(i,13).getValue();
    if (val == 1) {
      var speech = srcSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
      Logger.log(speech)
    }
  }
}
```

| D |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| 15 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| 20 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |

```
Execution log
5:47:46 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:47:46 PM  Info    5.0
5:47:46 PM  Info    15.0
5:47:46 PM  Info    20.0
5:47:47 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```